# upload large video files > 150mb in php

Tags: php

I have changed my `php.ini` file as below to upload large video files.

```
max_execution_time = 5000  

memory_limit = 1000M    

post_max_size = 750M    

file_uploads = On    

upload_max_filesize = 750M  

max_input_time = 5000
```

and refresh cache, but still cant upload video >100mb, pleae help. thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try? Where is your video upload form code? What is the PHP code that handles the upload? Is there any error that you are seeing, in browser or in logs?

Comment: Does your server config also allow that kind of upload?

Comment: With refreshing the cache do you mean restarting the server? Make sure to do that, check out phpinfo() to see if your php is linked to the right ini file and has your settings.

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads

Comment: Did you restart apache or nginx?